# How to do IO in a Widget/Hamlet referenced by defaultLayout?

Tags: haskell, yesod, shakespeare-text

I'm new to Yesod and seem to be completely lost with Widgets, Handlers, Hamlets, WHamlets, and what have you! Here's what I'm trying to do:

- Every page on my site needs to have a navbar, which leads me to believe that the correct place for implementing this should be `defaultLayout`
- Now, this navbar needs to display some information that is obtained from an IO action (it's an RPC call which gives this data, to be more specific).

Therefore, I tried writing the following function in `Foundation.hs` (the code layout is the basic `yesod-sqlite` scaffolding template):

```
nav = do
  globalStat <- handlerToWidget $ A2.getGlobalStat NWT.ariaRPCUrl
  $(whamletFile "templates/navbar.hamlet)

A2.getGlobalStat :: IO GlobalStatResponse
```

Here's what `template/navbar.hamlet` looks like:

```
<nav .navbar .navbar-default>
  <div .container-fluid>
    <p .navbar-right .navbar-text>
      <span>
        #{A2.glDownloadSpeed globalStat}
        <i .glyphicon .glyphicon-arrow-down>
      <span>
        #{A2.glUploadSpeed globalStat}
        <i .glyphicon .glyphicon-arrow-up>
      <span .label .label-success>
        On-the-watch
```

Here's what `default-layout-wrapper.hamlet` looks like:

```
<!-- SNIP -->
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <header>
        ^{nav}
      <div id="main" role="main">
        ^{pageBody pc}
<!-- SNIP -->
```

Here's what `defaultLayout` looks like:

```
defaultLayout widget = do
    master <- getYesod
    mmsg <- getMessage
    pc <- widgetToPageContent $ do
        addStylesheet $ StaticR css_bootstrap_css
        $(widgetFile "default-layout")
    withUrlRenderer $(hamletFile "templates/default-layout-wrapper.hamlet")
```

However, the code refuses to compile with one type-error after another. I've tried a lot of combinations of `hametFile`, `whamletFile`, `handerToWidget`, `liftIO`, even placing the nav function *inside* `defaultLayout`, but nothing seems to work. According to me my current code *should* compile, but I've obviously not understood how the Yesod-Core types are working.

How do I get this to work? And more importantly, what concept have I misunderstood?

**Edit 1:**

Have tried modifying the `nav` function to the following:

```
nav :: Handler Html
nav = do
  globalStat  <- liftIO $ A2.getGlobalStat NWT.ariaRPCUrl
  $(hamletFile "templates/navbar.hamlet")
```

But, it results in the following type mismatch in `defaultLayout` on the line with `withUrlRenderer`:

```
 Couldn't match type ‘HandlerT App IO Html’
                with ‘Text.Hamlet.Render (Route App) -> Html’
 Expected type: HtmlUrl (Route App)
   Actual type: Handler Html
 In the first argument of ‘Text.Hamlet.asHtmlUrl’, namely ‘nav’
 In a stmt of a 'do' block: Text.Hamlet.asHtmlUrl nav _render_a2ZY0 (intero)
```

**Edit 2:**

Tried changing the type signature of `nav` to:

```
nav :: Widget
nav = do
  globalStat  <- liftIO $ A2.getGlobalStat NWT.ariaRPCUrl
  $(hamletFile "templates/navbar.hamlet")
```

But it results in a new type-mismatch, in the same line:

```
 Couldn't match type ‘WidgetT App IO ()’
                with ‘Text.Hamlet.Render (Route App) -> Html’
 Expected type: HtmlUrl (Route App)
   Actual type: Widget
 In the first argument of ‘Text.Hamlet.asHtmlUrl’, namely ‘nav’
 In a stmt of a 'do' block: Text.Hamlet.asHtmlUrl nav _render_a350l (intero)
```

**Edit 3:**

Here's a relevant snippet from `-ddump-splices`:

```
\ _render_a28TE
  -> do { asHtmlUrl (pageHead pc) _render_a28TE;
          id ((Text.Blaze.Internal.preEscapedText . Data.Text.pack) "\n");
          asHtmlUrl (pageBody pc) _render_a28TE;
          id ((Text.Blaze.Internal.preEscapedText . Data.Text.pack) "\n");
          asHtmlUrl testWidget2 _render_a28TE }
```

The type of `(pageHead pc)` and `(pageBody pc)` is `HtmlUrl (Route App)`

Comment: Edited my question to post new code snippets based on the `liftIO` approach. Now, the problem seems to be that `^{nav}` usage in the `default-layout-wrapper` template doesn't seem to be composing well.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the answer to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23318426/yesods-shakespearean-templates-hamlet-and-io). Basically you can't perform IO in a template.

Also note that the type of `defaultLayout` is `GHandler ...` and `GHandler` is an [instance of MonadIO](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/yesod-0.4.1/docs/Yesod-Handler.html#t:GHandler), so you can perform IO in `defaultLayout` by using `liftIO`.

I would try:

```
defaultLayout = do
  ...
  globalStat <- liftIO $ handlerToWidget $ A2.getGlobalStat NWT.ariaRPCUrl
  uploadSpeed <- liftIO $ A2.glUploadSpeed globalStat
  downloadSpeed <- liftIO $ A2.glDownloadSpeed globalStat
  ...
  withUrlRenderer $(hamletFile "templates/default-layout-wrapper.hamlet")
```

And in `templates/default-layout-wrapper.hamlet`:

```
...
^{nav uploadSpeed downloadSpeed}
...
```

And `nav` becomes something like:

```
nav uploadSpeed downloadSpeed =   $(whamletFile "templates/navbar.hamlet)
```

So the basic ideas are:

- Do all of your IO in `defaultLayout` using `liftIO`
- Pass data needed by sub-templates as function arguments

**Update**

To emulate [this example in the Yesod book](http://www.yesodweb.com/book/yesods-monads#yesods-monads_example_database_driven_navbar) you need to write `navbar` like this:

```
navbar :: Widget
navbar = do
    globalStat <- liftIO A2.getGlobalStat NWT.ariaRPCUrl
    downloadSpeed <- liftIO A2.glDownloadSpeed globalStat
    uploadSpeed <- liftIO A.glUploadSpeed
    $(whamletFile "templates/navbar.hamlet)
```

And in `navbar.whamlet` refer to `#{uploadSpeed}` and `#{downloadSpeed}`.

You can't do IO in a whamlet file. Moreover, your A2 functions are IO-actions, but handlerToWidget requires a HandlerT action so you need to use `liftIO` to convert those calls.

**Update 2**

See http://lpaste.net/169497 for a working example which does IO in a Widget.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @ErikR. What would you say about http://www.yesodweb.com/book/yesods-monads#yesods-monads_example_database_driven_navbar ? Isn't what I'm trying to do similar?

Comment: Thanks, ErikR. it's still not working for me, but at least I've made some progress. Your suggestion of using `handlerToWidget $ liftIO` has resulted in a simpler type for the `nav` function, i.e. `nav :: (MonadIO m) => WidgetT site m ()`. However, this leads me to wonder why `liftIO` needed `handlerToWidget` in the first place. Why wasn't `liftIO` unable to lift the IO action directly to the `WidgetT site m ()` transformer stack?

Comment: My hunch was correct. The `handlerToWidget` is NOT actually required. Because I had not given a top-level type declaration, `liftIO` didn't know which monad to lift the IO action to. Simply added `nav :: Widget` as a top-level type declaration makes the `nav` function compile without `handlerToWidget`.

Comment: Thanks ErikR. I've managed to do IO inside a Handler action, but not in the original code I was targeting. I've reproduced the same error in your working example at http://lpaste.net/169497#a169504 Please take note of the `defaultLayout` implementation (this is what the yesod-sqlite scaffold gives). As soon as the `defaultLayout` is changed to this definition, the `lpaste-wrapper.hamlet` is unable to invoke `^{testWidget2}`or `^{testWidget}`

Comment: Probably the output of `-ddump-splices` can be helpful? Please take a look at my latest edit.

Comment: what do you think of my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38306902/534481

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I got this to work. There were actually two different problems I was facing:

- Doing IO inside a Widget
- Referencing a Widget in the `default-layout-wrapper` hamletFile.

Here's the solution for doing IO inside the widget:

```
nav :: Widget
nav = do
  globalStat <- liftIO $ A2.getGlobalStat NWT.ariaRPCUrl
  $(whamletFile "templates/navbar.hamlet")
```

**Note:** The type signature `nav :: Widget` seems to be necessary, else the type inference engine might get confused, and infer a very different type for the `liftIO` operation (which was originally happening with me).

For the second problem, I couldn't really find a solution for referencing a Widget within the `default-layout-wrapper` hamletFile. By the time this particular hamletFile is being rendered, the Widget monad has been converted to a `PageContent` type and now it needs an `Html url` type to be able to render it in conjunction with the `withUrlRenderer` function. Basically, I wasn't able to get `Widget` and `PageContent` to compose. However, the following approach gave me my desired result, in a different way:

**default-layout.hamlet:** Added the invocation to `nav` widget in this file. Moved some elements from `default-layout-wrapper` to this file:

```
<div .container>
  <header>
    ^{nav}
  <div #main role="main">
    $maybe msg <- mmsg
      <div #message>#{msg}
    ^{widget}
```

**default-layout-wrapper.hamlet:** Moved a few HTML element from this file to `default-layout`:

```
<!-- SNIP -->
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      ^{pageBody pc}
<!-- SNIP -->
```