# How to show current time with Yesod Template languages?

Tags: haskell, yesod

Since [IO can not be used inside Yesod Template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23318426/yesods-shakespearean-templates-hamlet-and-io), how can I display a simple current time on a page?

In my .hamlet file, something like:

```
<h2>
 #{show $ getCurrentTime } 

getCurrentTime :: IO UTCTime
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In other words, you need to run the IO action outside of the template.

That *outside* means the template's *handler*. So I would write like this.

```
-- Home.hs
getHomeR = do
  time <- liftIO getCurrentTime
  defaultLayout $(widgetFile "homepage")

-- homepage.hamlet
<h2>#{show time}
```

Comment: This `getCurrentTime` return time in UTC or in local timezone? What timezone will the user see in the browser?

Comment: @frt You can test it with ghci, `import Data.Time` `getCurrentTime`.
It will show us `2017-07-28 23:32:26.2083905 UTC` `it :: UTCTime`.